# none returns while solving time iterator

Tags: python-3.5

```
class TimeIterator:
    def __init__(self,start,stop):
        self.start=start
        self.stop=stop
        self.day=0
        self.hr=0
        self.sec=0



    def __getitem__(self,index):
        if index<self.stop-self.start:
            time=self.start+index
            day+=(((time//60)//60)%24)
            hr+=((time//60)%60)
            sec=(time%60)
        raise IndexError
        '{0:02d}:{1:02d}:{2:02d}'.format(day,hr,sec)      

start, stop, index=map(int, input().split())

for i in TimeIterator(start,stop):
    print(i)

print('\n', TimeIterator(start, stop)[index],sep='')
```

I'm trying to get results like
00:00:00
00:00:01
00:00:02

00:00:02

with the input 0 3 1
and I don't know what's wrong with the code here...Please help...

Comment: please indent your code so that we can understand what is the problem

Comment: I just formatted your code for you but also you should note, you have a syntax error on line 25, maybe that's why it is not working. I didn't have time to test it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a value to be returned by a function, you need to specify that value with a `return` statement.